# System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'x.y' is of type 'x' which is not supported by the current database provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I used data annotations validation before, Now I want to change Fluent Validation.
Because Now We change the project to clean architecture.

When I send the data from postman, The request goes to exception.

**System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'X.Overview' is of type 'XOverview' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.**

**when using dataannotations validation**

Domain X.cs

```
public class X
{
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public XOverview Overview { get; set; }
}
 public class XOverview
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

in DbConext.cs

```
public DbSet<XOverview> XOverview { get; set; }
// removed the rest
```

The above is working fine.

Now I want to change to **fluent validation.**

**when using fluent validation**

Domain X.cs

```
public class X
{
        public XOverview Overview { get; set; }
}
 public class XOverview
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

// Fluent validation for X

```
public class XConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<x>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<x> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(i => i.Id);

        builder.Property(i =>i.Overview)
                .IsRequired();
    }
}

public class XOverviewConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<XOverview>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<XOverview> builder)
    {
         builder.Property(i =>i.Id)
                .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(i =>i.Content)
                .IsRequired();
     
    }
}
```

What is the mistake I did when change to fluent validation ?
Please help to find the issue.

Comment: Where does the error appear? You can debug it. According to this article:https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24037

Comment: When I send a request from postman in debug console error is appear. 
Your suggestion is one to many relationship. Mine is one-to-one relationship. XOverview is an another table. When Creating a new X, a new XOverview will be automatically

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is not "fluent validation", but EF Core entity model fluent configuration.

Second, the concrete problem is this line

```cs
builder.Property(i =>i.Overview)
```

It's because by EF Core terminology, `Overview` is not a property, but *navigation property* (or simply navigation), hence is not allowed in methods called `Property(...)`. Instead, it can be used only in relationship configuring methods (`Has{One|Many}(...)` / `With({One|Many}(...)`) or the EF Core 5.0 introduced `Navigation(...)`.

So basically what you need is to replace `Property` with `Navigation`, e.g.

```cs
builder.Navigation(i => i.Overview)
    .IsRequired();
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thank you

Comment: But I have a doubt. XOverview is another table. Is ToTable() and Navigation() methods are same?

Comment: They are not. `ToTable` is configuring the associated table of the entity. For `XOverview` it should be inside `XOverviewConfiguration`. While `Navigation`  is configuring the relationship, from the side containing the navigation (I guess you know that every relationship has 2 sides). In this case you are configuring the relationship from `X` to `XOverview`. For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) topic in the official EF Core documentation).